# Can not solve Git error "refusing to merge unrelated histories"

Tags: django, git, amazon-web-services, atlassian-sourcetree

When I tried to pull

```
git pull https://myid@bitbucket.org/myid/abc.git
```

error occurred

> - branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
>   fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Then I tried this

```
 git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

error occurred

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could
> not read from remote repository.

Then I tried this

```
git mergetool
```

error occurred

> This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured. See
> 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
> 'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
> tortoisemerge emerge vimdiff No files need merging

Check branch name

```
git branch --contains=HEAD
```

branch is only master

> - master

I can not figure out how to fix this problem, please teach me what I can do next??

Comment: Try running `git remote -v`. What do you get?

Comment: Running "git remote -v" I got

origin  https://myid@bitbucket.org/myid/ruxxx.git (fetch)

origin  https://myid@bitbucket.org/myid/ruxxx.git (push)

What does it mean?

Comment: Those are the URLs that Git will fetch from and push to. Isn't there an `https://` before `myid`?

Comment: Yes there is https:// before myid